# return whole XML file instead of only the parsed value through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I  want to parse an XML file through JavaScript.

I wrote the following code, it works fine, but it displays only parsed values instead of the complete XML file.

```
function onDeviceReady()
{

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
           xmlhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
           xmlhttp.send();
           xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

}
```

I also tried responseXML instead of responseText, but it didn't work.

Comment: Dude, ajaxing and xml parsing, this entire thing is doable in just a few lines of jquery. I like to use JS as much as possible, but what you are doing is classic jquery functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its cause the browser parse the xml and show only the value. Its the same as open a xml direct in the browser. You have to replace all `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`, before setting the string as innerHTML.

Comment: I can't even get the server to response when I do the get.